# Xpages multy upload delete attachments

Tags: javascript, xpages

I've downloaded the following [opennsf](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/YouAtNotes%20HTML5%20Multi%20File%20Upload%20control). I would like to add for each document uploaded the option to delete if you choosed wrong. I managed to add a button in the script but I don't know how to link it to the attachment.

Here is the edited code:

```
var files = document.getElementById('ynFileUploadMulti').files;
        var html = '';
        if (files && files.length > 0) {        
        if(dojo.byId("ynFileUploadInfo").innerHTML == "" )  {
            html = '<table id="ynFileUpload" class="xspDataTableFileDownload" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:1em">';
            html += '<thead style="color:#545454;"><tr><th style="font-weight:bold;width:46px">Size</th><th style="font-weight:bold">Files to Upload</th><th style="font-weight:bold">Delete</th></tr></thead><tbody  style="color:#a0a0a0">';
            }
        else{
            html += dojo.byId("ynFileUploadInfo").innerHTML;
            html = html.replace("</tbody></table>", "");
        }
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var fileSize = 0;
                if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                 fileSize = (Math.round(file.size / (1024 * 1024))).toString() + ' MB';
                else
                 fileSize = (Math.round(file.size / 1024)).toString() + ' KB';
                html += '<tr><td>'+fileSize+'</td><td>'+file.name+'</td><td ><button onclick="myFunction()">x</button></td></tr>'
            }
            html += '</tbody></table>';
        }
        dojo.byId("ynFileUploadInfo").innerHTML = html;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ynUpload_onchange: "+e);
    }
```

This code is in the `ynUploader_onchange()` function. But I guess I need to touch the other function too (the ynUploader_worker(.....) function)?? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property "Allow Delete" in the File Download control or you can place a button on the xpage/cc with the following code to get a handle on the uploaded files

```
  var attList = document1.getAttachmentList("AttachmentRT");
    for(var i=0; i<attList.size(); i++) 
    {
        var att:String = attList[i];
        // Here you can process every uploaded file
    }
```

AttachmentRT ist the name of the notesrichtext field bound to the File Download